# Отображение view после редактирования?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Доброго времени суток, я внес дополнительную строку в шаблон view приложения(сайта) такой конфигурации:
front на react,
back на ROR,
деплой CAPISTRIANO,
веб сервер UNICORN+NGNIX.

Как собственно увидеть внесенное изменение не перезагружая сервер?

Comment: Так а в какую вьюху вы внесли изменения? В JSX реакта? Или в рельсовую?

Comment: app/views/templates видимо в рельсовую, .slim

Comment: У файла какие расширения?

Comment: Расширение файла .slim